# Promise within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, pinata

This code does not execute the promise of testAuthentication or pinFileToIPFS and i am curious if this is a node concept i am not familiar of.

```
function uploadToPinata(filename) {
    const pinata = pinataSDK(process.env.PINATA_KEY, process.env.PINATA_SECRET_KEY);
    pinata.testAuthentication().then((result) => {
        //handle successful authentication here
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        //handle error here
        console.log(err);
    });
    
    const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    const options = {
        pinataMetadata: {
            name: "NYC_NFT_TESTING",
        },
        pinataOptions: {
            cidVersion: 0
        }
    };

    pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile, options).then((result) => {
        //handle results here
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        //handle error here
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

is there a problem with this code using a promise within a function? I attemped to make the function async but that did not help. This code works just fine outside of a function but not within one.

Comment: A few things might happen. You might not be calling the function or the promise is never being resolved.

Comment: Everything starting with `const readableStreamForFile` is outside the promise callback, so it doesn't wait for the authentication to complete. Everything that depends on successful authentication should be in the `.then()` function.

Comment: Or rewrite this using `await`.

Comment: i have tried using await and also tried to put the second promise within the first promise callback.  Both unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"does not execute the promise"*: this is a strange phrase. Promises are objects. They don't *execute* -- they are *created*. And your function really creates them. However, it does not do much when these promises are resolved.

The problem is that `uploadToPinata` will execute all of the synchronous code and return. But then there are still a promises pending. Although you have `console.log` that will be executed once the relevant promise has resolved, there is no signal to the caller of `uploadToPinata` that these promises have resolved.

It is probably easiest to use `async` and `await`:

```
async function uploadToPinata(filename) {
    const pinata = pinataSDK(process.env.PINATA_KEY, process.env.PINATA_SECRET_KEY);
    const result = await pinata.testAuthentication();
    //handle successful authentication here
    console.log("authentication result", result);
    const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    const options = {
        pinataMetadata: { name: "NYC_NFT_TESTING" },
        pinataOptions: { cidVersion: 0 }
    };

    const result2 = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile, options);
    //handle results here
    console.log("pinFileToIPFS result", result2);
}
```

The caller of this function will now receive a promise, so it should probably want to do something when that promise has resolved:

```
uploadToPinata(filename).then(() => {
    console.log("authentication and file operation done")
}).catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```